# my code is giving me the wrong output sometimes, how to solve it?

Tags: python

I am trying to solve this problem: 'Your task is to construct a building which will be a pile of n cubes. The cube at the bottom will have a volume of n^3, the cube above will have the volume of (n-1)^3 and so on until the top which will have a volume of 1^3.
You are given the total volume m of the building. Being given m can you find the number n of cubes you will have to build?
The parameter of the function findNb (find_nb, find-nb, findNb) will be an integer m and you have to return the integer n such as n^3 + (n-1)^3 + ... + 1^3 = m if such a n exists or -1 if there is no such n.'

I tried to first create an arithmetic sequence then transform it into a sigma sum with the nth term of the arithmetic sequence, the get a formula which I can compare its value with m.

I used this code and work 70 - 80% fine, most of the calculations that it does are correct, but some don't.

```
import math


def find_nb(m):
    n = 0
    while n < 100000:
        if (math.pow(((math.pow(n, 2))+n), 2)) == 4*m:
            return n
            break
        n += 1
    return -1


print(find_nb(4183059834009))
>>> output 2022, which is correct
print(find_nb(24723578342962))
>>> output -1, which is also correct
print(find_nb(4837083252765022010))
>>> real output -1, which is incorrect
>>> expected output 57323
```

Comment: `break` following a `return` is unnecessary.

Comment: I know but I didn't figure another way to get -1 not None

Comment: Why is the `n` initialisation 2021? Why don't you start with some function of `m` instead? Like iterate backwards from its cube root.  I can't find anything "wrong" right now with the logic, but I haven't calculated the sum myself. Have you input the expected output and input into your equation in the if condition to check if it works?

Comment: How should find_nb(4837083252765022010) return 57323? When n = 57323, the sum of cubes from 1^3 to n^3 is n^2(n+1)^2/4 which is around 2.7e18 not 4.8e18.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned, this is a math problem, which is mainly what I am better at :).
Sorry for the in-line mathematical formula as I cannot do any math formula rendering (in SO).

*I do not see any problem with your code and I believe your sample test case is wrong. However, I'll still give optimisation "tricks" below for your code to run quicker*

Firstly as you know, sum of the cubes between 1^3 and n^3 is n^2(n+1)^2/4. Therefore we want to find integer solutions for the equation

`n^2(n+1)^2/4 == m` i.e. `n^4+2n^3+n^2 - 4m=0`

Running a loop for `n` from 1 (or in your case, 2021) to `100000` is **inefficient**. Firstly, if m is a large number (1e100+) the complexity of your code is O(n^0.25). Considering Python's runtime, you can run your code in time only if m is less than around `1e32`.

To optimise your code, you have two approaches.

1) Use **[Binary Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36682383/finding-roots-of-a-function-with-binary-search-and-recursion)**. I will not get into the details here, but basically, you can **halve** the search range for a simple comparison. For the initial `bounds` you can use `lower = 0 & upper = k`. A better bound for `k` will be given below, but let's use `k = m` for now.

**Complexity: O(log(k)) = O(log(m))**

**Feasible range for m: m < 10^(3e7)**

2) Use the almighty **[Newton-Raphson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method)**!! Using the iteration formula `x_(n+1) = x_n - f(x_n) / f'(x_n)`, where `f'(x)` can be calculated explicitly, and a reasonable initial guess, let's say `k = m` again, the complexity is (I believe) O(log(k)) + O(1) = O(log(m)).

**Complexity: O(log(k)) = O(log(m))**

**Feasible range for m: m < 10^(3e7)**

Finally, I'll give a better initial guess for `k` in the above methods, also given in Ian's answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1865688/what-is-the-computational-complexity-of-newton-raphson-method-to-find-square-roo). Since `n^4+2n^3+n^2 = O(n^4)`, we can actually take `k ~ m^0.25 = (m^0.5)^0.5`. To calculate this, We can take `k = 2^(log(k)/4)` where log is base 2. The log should be O(1), but I'm not sure for big numbers/dynamic size (int in Python). Not a theorist. Using this better guess and Newton-Raphson, since the guess is in a constant range from the result, the algorithm is nearly O(1). Again, check out the links for better understanding.

**Finally**

Since your goal is to find whether `n` exists such that the equation is "exactly satisfied", use Newton-Raphson and iterate until the next guess is less than 0.5 from the current guess. If your implementation is "floppy", you can also do a range +/- 10 from the guess to ensure that you find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a Math question rather than a programming question.

Firstly, I would advise you to start iterating from a function of your input `m`. Right now you are initialising your `n` value arbitrarily (though of course it might be a requirement of the question) but I think there are ways to optimise it. Maybe, just maybe you can iterate from the cube root, so if `n` reaches zero or if at any point the sum becomes smaller than `m` you can safely assume there is no possible building that can be built.

Secondly, the equation you derived from your summation doesn't seem to be correct. I substituted your expected `n` and input `m` into the condition in your if clause and they don't match. So either 1) your equation is wrong or 2) the expected output is wrong. I suggest that you relook at your derivation of the condition. Are you using the sum of cubes factorisation? There might be some edge cases that you neglected (maybe odd `n`) but my Math is rusty so I can't help much.

Of course, as mentioned, the `break` is unnecessary and will never be executed.

Comment: Formula is: `(n*(n+1)/2)^2 = m` or `n^4 + n^2 = 4*m`.

Comment: @ipaleka `(n^2+n)^2 = n^4+2n^3+n^2 != n^4+n^2` *Facepalm in MathSO* `(a+b)^2!=a^2+b^2`

Comment: @ipaleka Both evaluate to false. I think you need to check your summation.

Comment: Yep, that was so early in the morning for CET (after a programming night). Sorry, totally lost that `n^2 + 2n + 1`.